# How to get a value when clicked into another div?

Tags: jquery

Hi all i am working on jquery actually i am new for it here what i have to do is i have `stock50` like `items` and `price$99` of that items (stock) in one div right and i have a one more separate div and i have a `imagebutton` when click on the imagebutton the item (stock) which is having it should add one item to my another div and the stock should decrease like remaining `stock49` means items and price$99 for each item if i suppose selected two items the remaining `stock48` and 2 items shold add to my div and price  should be double so this is what i have to do i don't have any idea plz help are suggestme

here some code follows:

```
         <div class="conteinar">
     <div class="product">
        <img src="images/2215460001_14980_png_picture_1.png" />
        <span>Stock 10</span>
        <span>Price $99</span>
        <span><img src="images/ADDCart.png" /></span>
        </div>

        <div class="product">
        <img src="images/2215460001_14980_png_picture_1.png" />
        <span>Stock 50</span>
        <span>Price $99</span>
        <span><img src="images/ADDCart.png" /></span>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to take a hidden field for every product. In hidden field value  which product quantity. Then when any one click on add to cart get value from `hidden field` and `decrease` 1 then set to `SPAN` for display.

Answer (score 0):

You can use data-* attributes to store the counts in the spans. You can add the attribute with jQuery this way:

```
$('spanSelector').attr('data-itemCount', '50');
```

So, when you need to remove an item from that list, subtract from the count and set it to the `data-count` custom attribute:

```
var newCount = parseInt($('spanSelector').attr('data-itemCount'))-1;
$('spanSelector').attr('data-itemCount', newCount);
```

You'll also want to update your display text as well with the new count:

```
'Stock ' + $('spanSelector').attr('data-itemCount');
```

You can do the same thing with the price. Store it as data-price and just retrieve it in the same manner and add it to your total.

This should get you started in the right direction. Data-* attributes are a nice way to store data in the DOM. You don't want to store tons upon tons of data-* attributes, but for what you're talking, this is a good route to take.